# how to login AliExpress with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, aliexpress

i'm trying to login automatically to AliExpress.com and i can't find the username and password boxes.
i'm using Selenium with Python 3 on windows.
i've tried this so far,  this is the start:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com')
driver.find_element_by_name("SearchText").send_keys("iphone 11")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-button").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.maximize_window()
```

the continuation attempts are:

```
find_elements_by_class_name("login-content nc-outer-box")
```

or

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("login-password")
```

or

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fm-field")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("input-plain-wrap input-wrap-loginid ").send_keys("blahblah@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("fm-login-password").send_keys("blahblah")
```

for the first 50 search AliExpress let me see the results before I had to login but now I have to and all of my attempts failed, any ideas what should I do? 
(every time I saved "fields" I got it's length is 0 instead of 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try following selectors for username & password fields:

**username selectors :**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.input-plain-wrap.input-wrap-loginid").send_keys("blahblah@gmail.com")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#fm-login-id").send_keys("blahblah@gmail.com")
```

**password selectors :**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.input-plain-wrap.input-wrap-password").send_keys("password")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#fm-login-password").send_keys("password")
```